# I can not save date in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, razor

I've this model which has a couple of columns and one of them is date, but on post I get nothing of date, only in case if I give it the value of **DateTime.Now** then it will save the current date but If had selected some other date in the datepicker it will not save that as it should, so How can I pass the date to the view model on post, I can pass all the date from dropdown and textboxes but date is no where to found. Here is the code 
My view model

```
[Display(Name = "Requested Date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? RequestDate { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Job Number")]
public string JobNo { get; set; }
```

Here is the Post Create method code

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var model = new PECEquipmentRequest()
    {
        ProjectId = pecEquipmentRequest.ProjectId,
        JobNo = pecEquipmentRequest.JobNo,
        RequestDate = pecEquipmentRequest.RequestDate
    };
    db.PECEquipmentRequests.Add(model);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

and here is the my razor syntax

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RequestDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = DateTime.Now,@class = "form-control datepicker" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RequestDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the kendo date picker that I'm using

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
});
```

Comment: Use `Html.TextBoxFor`

Comment: You need to remove `@Value = DateTime.Now` - NEVER set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods. If you ant the default date to be `DateTime.Now`, then set the value in the model before you pass it to the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke As you can [see](http://prntscr.com/a6etjb) still nothing happened the date is still null

Comment: @Shyju the date picker disappears with 'TextBoxFor' and even if I manually add the date it still shows the null

Comment: If its `null` its because you have not selected a date, or have not initially set a value in the model before passing it to the view. But why do you have a `class="datepicker"` for that control. It suggests your using a jQuery datepicker plugin (in which case your `[DisplayFormat]` and `[DataType]` attributes are pointless. And if you are using a datepicker plugin, then show the relevant code!

Comment: I'm using kendo date picker and date is not null I do select the date here is the datepicker code its simple 
    $(document).ready(function () {
       

        $(".datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
    });

Comment: Edit your question with the relevant code (not in comments)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please check it now

Comment: If the value is `null` then the issue is with the datepicker. I suggest you first comment out the script and just test using the HTML5 datepicker (which is what is generated by your `[DisplayFormat]` and `[DataType]` attributes). But the fact you noted previously that _date picker disappears with `TextBoxFor()`_ suggests other problems as well.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Even after using TextBoxFor() and given it format "{0:d}" it does not do any good

Comment: Using `TextBoxFor()` and manually entering a valid date will work just fine. If its not, then there is other code you have not shown use that is causing the problem.

Comment: well let me remove all other third party stuff and use simple HTML 5 date stuff then will see what happens

Comment: and even in that case if it works it will not work with Old Gold Wanker IE

Comment: @StephenMuecke Okay I removed every thing, every script in that case it does save the date but it only works in Chrome and no where else

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to confirm it was the datepicker plugin that was causing the issue (and note that the `[DisplayFormat]` and `[DataType]` attributes can be removed - their only purpose is to generate the HTML5 datepicker which is only supported in Chrome and Edge)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the date to the required format in the server side.

DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);